# _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError 1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check

Tags: python, mysql, database, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
for toolx in tools:
    print toolx

output_count = """SELECT count(tool),count(""SELECT count(tool) FROM 
               core_data WHERE sentiment = 'positive' AND tool = '%s'"") 
               from core_data where tool = '%s'""" % (toolx, toolx)
```

I don't know how to compare against strings while running multiple sql statements in a query.

Comment: Please fix indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have couple of issues with your code.

First, you should use place holders for parameters and pass parameters as tuple to `cursor` when executing SQL query. This way MySQL will guard you from SQL injection attacks to some extent.

Example:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM core_data WHERE sentiment = 'positive' AND tool = %s",  (toolx,))
```

Second issue is when you do the counting of all positive sentiments. You would be much better with:

```
SELECT count(*) as 'All count', 
       sum(case when sentiment = 'positive' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Positive Sentiments'
FROM core_data 
WHERE tool = %s
```

To wrap up, here is how it should look:

```
for toolx in tools:
    print toolx
    query = "SELECT count(*) as 'All count', sum(case when sentiment = 'positive' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Positive Sentiments' FROM core_data WHERE tool = %s"
    results = cursor.execute(query, (toolx,))
    # and then you do the fetchone and take counts
```